# Skip slow loading ULRs in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I started learning Selenium and i got stuck at some point, i must say i'm quite not sure how to explain the issue i'm having, but i'll make it simple.
So let's say we have 5 different URLs, i need to go through them and see if they redirect properly using:

```
driver.get(*insert URL here*);
```

Let's give the following URLs:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/
2. https://github.com/
3. https://duckduckgo.com/
4. https://www.javatpoint.com/
5. https://www.toolsqa.com/

i have a loop going though `driver.get(*insert URL here*);`, and i notice that the 4th URL is painfully slow it wont even move to the 5th URL, how do i skip it if it reaches, let's say, 15 sec ?

Here's my java code :

```
    for(int i=0; i<mediasCAS.length; i++){
        if(mediasCAS[i][4] != "?") {
            driver.get(mediasCAS[i][4]);
        }
        else
            continue;
        System.out.println("Site Name : "+mediasCAS[i][1]);
    }
```

the mediasCAS is a 2D array that contains the websites informations where the 4th column contains the URLs.

Comment: How about `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Fenio, i'm afraid that this line of code causes my test to stop completely, raising a timeout exception, and won't continue to the next URL.
Nonetheless, i must say that is a great way to check what URL will slow down my test.

Comment: Just use try-catch block and use `continue;` to proceed with for loop

Comment: Thanks, @Fenio ! this will do the job, although i'm kind of feeling that there is a proper way of doing this, but so far, this worked like a charm !

Comment: I posted the comments as the answer. Kindly accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium allows to use method `pageLoadTimeout()`.

From the Javadoc:

> Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error.
>   If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

Combining it with `try-catch` you can just ignore the exception and continue with `for` loop like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
for(int i=0; i<mediasCAS.length; i++){
    try {
        if(mediasCAS[i][4] != "?") {
            driver.get(mediasCAS[i][4]);
        }
        else
            continue;
        System.out.println("Site Name : "+mediasCAS[i][1]);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        continue;
    }
}
```